# DbConnection.StateChange not called when connection is disposed?

Tags: c#, semaphore, idisposable, dbconnection

I have a singleton database class which may be accessed from hundreds of threads simultaneously. Each thread gets its own connection. Since I cannot control the number of threads, I need to limit the number of concurrent connections. I decided to use a **semaphore** as shown below. Now, the connection is always assigned in a `using` block so it is indeed guaranteed to get closed - even if an exception is thrown.

However, it seems that [StateChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.statechange.aspx) is **not called** when an exception is thrown. Obviously, this breaks my code below.

**QUESTION:** How do I make sure `StateChange` is indeed called in this scenario? Or, if not possible, how do I solve this particular problem?

```
private const int MAX_CONNECTIONS = 10;
private static SemaphoreSlim connectionLock = new SemaphoreSlim(MAX_CONNECTIONS);

protected DbConnection OpenConnection()
{
    var connection = ProviderFactory.CreateConnection();
    connection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
    connection.Open();

    connectionLock.Wait();

    connection.StateChange += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (e.CurrentState == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            connectionLock.Release();
        }
    };

    return connection;
}
```

Comment: Can i ask why you can't use the default ADO.NET [`Connection-Pooling`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17768/ADO-NET-Connection-Pooling-at-a-Glance)?

Comment: Not sure how that would help? If the maximum number of connections is reached, the threads should wait as shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok... It seems the event is indeed called IF the exception is produced *after* the call to `OpenConnection`. When I tested this, I put an explicit `throw new Exception()` just before returning the connection... oops!